# How to make two images responsive with fixed height and plain CSS?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make the two images  responsive with a fixed height similar to [here](http://jamesturrell.com/work/type/).

I created the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnxz7co9/4/)

Somehow the line break is added too soon. I tried to add `width=auto` however this did not work. Moreover it would be good if after a certain width it would become a single column.

Comment: Is your question about having two images per row?

Comment: Yes that would good. however after a certain screen size it should be only one. But initially two images per row would be good.

Comment: If you want the images to wrap to a new line when the container becomes too small you will need to set a width for the images. You could do `display: flex` on the container and also set `flex-wrap: wrap`. If you want the images to scale with the container and display a different number of images per row based on display width, I believe you will need to set the images per row width media queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not super clear what you're asking but there are a few ways to make images responsive with a fixed height and fluid width.

The easiest of which is to use the `object-fit: cover` rule. Try adding `object-fit: cover` to your `.image` element.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp

This should force it to fill its container without warping its dimensions.

If you want to build a 2-column grid, you need to set the width of the containers using calc, and remove the margin-right on all the even containers.

```
.container {
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.container:nth-child(2n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 412px;
}
```

I modified your js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hnxz7co9/34/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Now I only need to add the behavior when the screen size is smaller than 700pt. I think it was something with ` @media (max-width:700px)`. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your images don't go two to a line is that you haven't allowed enough room for them to do that. You have set your image width at 48%. If you add up all the horizontal margins and horizontal padding outside of your images, you'll find that they add up to more than four percent of the available width, so your second image gets bounced to the next line. I found in your jsfiddle that changing the image width to 47%, or changing your right margin to 10px, or changing your right margin to 1% allowed two images per row.

If you express a width as a percentage and your padding and margins as pixels, you have to calculate the total pixels involved and make sure that there's enough room for two images to fit on a line. To do this, you can use the `calc()` function as in Daniel Bernardi's answer, or if you want the margins to resize along with your image size, you can set them as percentages rather than hard pixel values.

As for changing to one image per row on smaller screens, I would start by reading about [`@media`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp). This allows you to set up different CSS rules for screens of different sizes. So, if your screen is below a certain size, set the width of the image to 100% minus padding and margins.

Comment: Thanks your explanation helped me to understand the background better. And `@media` annotation was the next keyword I needed to read about so thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Actually When You A image tell display block and height some value then you most declared 
 **Width: auto**

when you tell an image width some value then tell height auto.

> **when you break this option your image see stretch, you want one side fee height or width.**

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
}

.site-content {
    position: relative;
}

.max-column {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.container {
    width: 42%;
    height: 412px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    height: 412px;
    width: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(70%);
    -o-filter: brightness(70%);
    -ms-filter: brightness(70%);
    filter: brightness(70%);
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="site-content max-column">

        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/10f/autumn-1-1382513.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">

                    <h1>Works</h1>
                    <p> Is the music</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e01/lrt-interior-1626389.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">

                    <h1>Works</h1>

                    <p> Is the music</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/035/young-golden-retriever-1404848.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
            <div class="middle">
                <div class="text">

                    <h1>Works</h1>

                    <p> Is the music</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

==**thanks**==

Answer (score 0):

you have to use background image instead of image

```
<div class="site-content max-column">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image img1"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Works</h1>
                <p> Is the music</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image img2"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Works</h1>
                <p> Is the music</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="image img3"></div>
        <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">
                <h1>Works</h1>
                <p> Is the music</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 1280px;
}

.site-content {
    position: relative;
}

.max-column {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.container {
    width: 48%;
    height: 412px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    line-height: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    height: 412px;
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
    -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
    -moz-filter: brightness(70%);
    -o-filter: brightness(70%);
    -ms-filter: brightness(70%);
    filter: brightness(70%);
    opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.container:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
}

.text {
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
}
.img1{
    background: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/10f/autumn-1-1382513.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
.img2{
    background: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e01/lrt-interior-1626389.jpg');
}
.img3{
    background: url('https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/035/young-golden-retriever-1404848.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v940y2pg/8)

Answer (score 0):

Play around with the values and you will see how effects elements.

```css
h1 {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.image {
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.grid_img {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(500px, 1fr));
  
/*    you need SCSS for this:
    
     @media (max-width: 990px) {
        .grid_cards {
          grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(200px, 1fr));
        }
*/
```

```html
<div class="grid_img">
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <h1>Some Image here</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
```