# Make 3 images the same size (Complete Example)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this very basic example but I'm not able to create a row of images that looks good.

In my example the images look stretched.

Is there a way to improve this?

```css
.site {
  background: #000;
}

.partners img{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="site">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/48/FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg/640px-FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freebiesupply/large/2x/ing-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.careinternational.org.uk/linking-for-change/images/Barclays-Ross-Kingsland.png" />
    </div>
  </dpaiv>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/rbs-400775.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.sundaypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2016/05/banks-900x540.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.leftovercurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/the-royal-bank-of-scotland-plc-10-pounds-banknote-obverse-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `background-size: cover;` not working with `img` tag, it's only work with background image.

Comment: Do you need you images to be 100% width?

Comment: the height should be the same and the width should be +- the col-md-4 length

Answer (score 1):

> when you break this option your image see stretch, you want one side
>   fee height or width.

```css
.site {
  background: #000;
}

.partners img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="site">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/48/FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg/640px-FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freebiesupply/large/2x/ing-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.careinternational.org.uk/linking-for-change/images/Barclays-Ross-Kingsland.png" />
    </div>
  </dpaiv>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/rbs-400775.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.sundaypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2016/05/banks-900x540.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.leftovercurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/the-royal-bank-of-scotland-plc-10-pounds-banknote-obverse-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See more details [How to make two images responsive with fixed height and plain CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51406835/how-to-make-two-images-responsive-with-fixed-height-and-plain-css/51407523#51407523)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.site {
  background: #000;
}

.partners img{
  height:100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="site">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/48/FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg/640px-FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freebiesupply/large/2x/ing-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.careinternational.org.uk/linking-for-change/images/Barclays-Ross-Kingsland.png" />
    </div>
  </dpaiv>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/rbs-400775.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.sundaypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2016/05/banks-900x540.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.leftovercurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/the-royal-bank-of-scotland-plc-10-pounds-banknote-obverse-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or

```css
.site {
  background: #000;
}

.partners img{
  width:100px;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="site">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/48/FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg/640px-FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freebiesupply/large/2x/ing-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.careinternational.org.uk/linking-for-change/images/Barclays-Ross-Kingsland.png" />
    </div>
  </dpaiv>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/rbs-400775.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.sundaypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2016/05/banks-900x540.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.leftovercurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/the-royal-bank-of-scotland-plc-10-pounds-banknote-obverse-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tried `background-size`, you should take a look at `object-fit` which is accurate to image, results are very much alike `background-size`/`background-image`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

> The `object-fit` CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element, such as an `<img>` or `<video>`, should be resized to fit its container.

```css
.site {
  background: #000;
}

.partners img{
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="site">
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/4/48/FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg/640px-FIS_%28company%29_Fidelity_National_Information_Services_Inc._Corporate_Logo.svg.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freebiesupply/large/2x/ing-logo-png-transparent.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.careinternational.org.uk/linking-for-change/images/Barclays-Ross-Kingsland.png" />
    </div>
  </dpaiv>
  <div class="row d-flex">
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/rbs-400775.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.sundaypost.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/13/2016/05/banks-900x540.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 partners">
      <img src="https://www.leftovercurrency.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/the-royal-bank-of-scotland-plc-10-pounds-banknote-obverse-1.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> ## Syntax
>
> The `object-fit` property is specified as a single keyword chosen from the list of values below.
>   Values
>
> **contain**
>       The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting within the element’s content box. The entire object is made to fill the box, while preserving its aspect ratio, so the object will be "letterboxed" if its aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of the box.
>
> **cover**
>       The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element’s entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be clipped to fit.
>
> **fill**
>       The replaced content is sized to fill the element’s content box. The entire object will completely fill the box. If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be stretched to fit.
>
> **none**
>       The replaced content is not resized.
>
> **scale-down**
>       The content is sized as if none or contain were specified, whichever would result in a smaller concrete object size.

---

Other image-related CSS properties: [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position), [`image-orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-orientation), [`image-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering), [`image-resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-resolution).